# Hashmode Stripe CakePHP plugin Library not found

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, stripe-payments

I am having an issue with a CakePHP Plugin

Error:
    "Stripe PHP Library not found. Be sure it is unpacked in app/Vendor/stripe directory. It can be downloaded from https://stripe.com/docs/libraries"

```
if (!class_exists('Stripe\Stripe')) {
        throw new CakeException('Stripe PHP Library not found. Be sure it is unpacked in app/Vendor/stripe directory.
                                It can be downloaded from https://stripe.com/docs/libraries');
    }
```

https://github.com/hashmode/CakePHP-Stripe-Component-Full

Using CakePHP 2.9

Stripe 3.14

Path to Stripe.php is app\Vendor\stripe\lib\Stripe.php

I am including in my controller as follows

```
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Stripe');
```

And calling with

```
$this->Stripe->createCustomer();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in their component file, incorrect path has been declared.
In StripeComponent.php line 4, replace

```
$path = $base . 'lib' . str_replace('Stripe\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
```

with

```
$path = $base . 'stripe' . DS . 'lib' . str_replace('Stripe\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
```

and it should start working.